# Set Checkbox Text Value from a listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How Can I Bind checkbox content value for every item that will be added to my listbox?

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="2" Height="389" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
 Name="lboIssues" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175"
 SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
```

Then Here's my ItemTemplate

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,5" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <CheckBox   Name="checkbox"
                Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                Width="Auto"
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                IsTabStop="False" Checked="FilterCheckbox_CheckChanged" 
                Unchecked="FilterCheckbox_CheckChanged"/>
   </StackPanel>                         
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>`
```

As I check, checkboxes' content value were blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying changing it to

```
    <CheckBox   Name="checkbox"
                Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,0,5,0"
                Width="Auto"
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                IsTabStop="False" Checked="FilterCheckbox_CheckChanged" 
                Unchecked="FilterCheckbox_CheckChanged"
                Content="{Binding}"/>
```